# Is there ever more than one code segment active at a time in an ESLint Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: eslint

I'm reading [this article](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/code-path-analysis) on code path analysis in ESLint, and I came across this code which demonstrates how to keep track of code paths and code path segments.

To give some background, a *code path* corresponds to every function definition in the code (and also the program itself), and a *code path segment* corresponds to each branch of code within the code path. Because function definitions can be nested, a new code path can be created within a segment.

In the following code, the `create` method returns an object containing event handlers whose names are self-explanatory: e.g., when ESlint traverses the AST, it calls the event handler `onCodePathStart()` when it encounters the start of a code path.

The variable `currentCodePath` always contains the current code path. it is set when we enter a code path, and when we leave a code path, it is reset to the containing code path (`codePath.upper`).

The variable `currentSegments`, likewise, keeps track of the current segment(s).
What I don't understand is when, if ever, this variable actually ever contains more than one segment. You can see in the code that when we enter a segment, the segment is added to it, but when we leave a segment, it is also deleted. Therefore, it seems like there should only ever be one segment in it, so why is a `Set` used? My experiments with different code examples have not managed to uncover any case of `currentSegments` ever containing more than one segment.

At first, I thought it might be to do with segments being nested, but as far as I can gather, segments are discrete within a single code path. And you can see in the code that whenever we enter a new code path, the `codeSegments` variable is reset.

Perhaps, it's just convenient to store `codeSegments` as a `Set` (or as an array in some other examples), but is that the case, or is there something I haven't understood and there can be more than one active code segment at a time? if so, when would that be?

```
module.exports = {
    meta: {
        // ...
    },
    create(context) {

        // tracks the code path we are currently in
        let currentCodePath;

        // tracks the segments we've traversed in the current code path
        let currentSegments;

        // tracks all current segments for all open paths
        const allCurrentSegments = [];

        return {

            onCodePathStart(codePath) {
                currentCodePath = codePath;
                allCurrentSegments.push(currentSegments);
                currentSegments = new Set();
            },

            onCodePathEnd(codePath) {
                currentCodePath = codePath.upper;
                currentSegments = allCurrentSegments.pop();
            },

            onCodePathSegmentStart(segment) {
                currentSegments.add(segment);
            },

            onCodePathSegmentEnd(segment) {
                currentSegments.delete(segment);
            },

            onUnreachableCodePathSegmentStart(segment) {
                currentSegments.add(segment);
            },

            onUnreachableCodePathSegmentEnd(segment) {
                currentSegments.delete(segment);
            }
        };

    }
};
```

Comment: _Did not dive into the matter!_ But has this nothing to do with control flow, and on encountering a conditional or switch branch increasing the set?

Comment: kind of. the question is why is a Set being used when it doesn't ever appear to contain more than a single element?